# Fetch a particular attribute from list of objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like below

```
[
<NodeImage: id=aki-00501552,
name=ubuntu/kernels-testing/ubuntu-lucid-amd64-linux-image-2.6.32-341-ec2-v-2.6.32-341.42-kernel,
driver=AmazonEC2(ap-southeast-1)...>,
<NodeImage: id=aki-00c4bd52,
name=ubuntu-kernels/ubuntu-lucid-amd64-linux-image-2.6.32-316-ec2-v-2.6.32-316.31-kernel,
driver=AmazonEC2(ap-southeast-1)...>,
<NodeImage: id=aki-015d1253,
name=RH-pv-grub-hd00-V1.01-x86_64,
driver=AmazonEC2(ap-southeast-1)...>
]
```

The list contains multiple "NodeImage" and each of them have id,name and driver attributes under them. How do I fetch all the id's and store in a different list?

Comment: `[node.id for node in list_of_nodes]`? You have a list of `NodeImage` objects, not a *"list of list"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of objects; to create a list of the values of a specific attributes, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
ids = [node.id for node in list_of_nodes]
```

If not all your objects have the attribute, you could include a filter:

```
ids = [node.id for node in list_of_nodes if hasattr(node, 'id')]
```

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting this following error. AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id' .

Comment: @sangamesh: so your list contains at least one string too. The code assumes that all your objects have an `id` attribute. Clean up your list (make sure it only contains the correct type of objects) or use `if hasattr(node, 'id')` in the comprehension.

Comment: I am getting an empty list with this :/

Comment: @sangamesh: then *update your question* with your *actual* list contents. Do not type them in as a guess. Use `print(repr(your_actual_list))`. You do **not** have a list of `NodeImage` instances, but one with strings or something else.

Comment: @Martijin I was making a small mistake. Fixed it. Thank you!